# Versioning microservices in trunk based development

Tags: architecture, microservices

Given a system built using microservices (somewhat diverified tech stack - parts in ASP.NET Core, Node.js, React, python - the right tool for the job etc etc). The whole system is to be released to end users in fixed increments (let's say each sprint), in a "trunk based development approach". That is, the system is devloped using feature teams able to work on all components. How would you version each microservice? The system as a whole is what the end user faces and what can be tested using integration tests etc.

I can find two alternatives.

1. Build every service at release (or simply use last successful build from master). The version of a service is merly the "build number" or "build time".
2. Version each service using semantic versioning and track each service for each release.

I'm leaning at #1. Seems like the easy way out. What is the best practice? Monolith/single framework is not an option.

Comment: Issue with #1 is if something is broken in at least one the builds, there is very little traceability of where the problem might be. I'm working on a tool - Reliza Hub - which solves exactly this problem on bundling. Here are my overall thoughts on the issue - https://worklifenotes.com/2020/11/15/devops-bundles-new-name-of-the-game/

Comment: Thanks for input. @taleodor I take your input to suggest going with automated versioning of each component?

Comment: Yes, briefly our way of doing this: every component is auto-versioned, then there is an integration instance over which bundles are created and auto-recorded (bundle = snapshot of all component versioning). Once you are happy with a state of the integration instance, you approve a specific bundle, and this becomes final release. This may be further refined with multiple environments (i.e. test-uat-staging) and various gates (i.e. auto-tests). Key idea is that bundle becomes an atomic releasable unit which makes problem tractable.

Comment: The above is applicable if you need bundled approach - which is usually the case for regulated industries. Example where people usually do not use bundled approach - SaaS for an unregulated industry. There common pattern is to just use latest version of each component with some API-level contracts (somewhat similar to your #1 approach). So it also depends on what situation you are in.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with trunk based development has led me to use [semantic release](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/) or its python variant [python-semantic-release](https://python-semantic-release.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). These are pretty standard tools which are able to parse your angular style commit message based on commits in the trunk and accordingly bump the version, push git tags and even release packages to artifactory. However, in the case of micro-services it would suffice to bump the version and push the git tags, which can then be used as a version for the docker images (assuming that you have micro-services which run inside pods based on the docker images).